# How to save FileField with None in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model Profile with Avatar field use FileField.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.FileField(
        "Uploaded avatar of profile",
        storage=OverwriteStorage(),
        upload_to=avatar_photo_upload,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I write function to remove avatar, which set avatar = None

```
def remove_avatar(self, request):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile.avatar = None
        profile.avatar.save()
        return Response({ 'status': 'ok', 'message': 'Avatar successfully removed' }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In my database, avatar stored as `''`, not `null`. Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.FileField(
        "Uploaded avatar of profile",
        storage=OverwriteStorage(),
        upload_to=avatar_photo_upload,
        null=True,
    )
```

remove the `blank` option

Comment: Did this ever work? At least it does not work in Django 3.2. Try and see: `Profile.objects.create(avatar=None).avatar is not None` Instead, you still get a `<FieldFile: None>`.

Comment: @djvg no, it didn't and still does not. The one way I found is to override `django.db.models.fields.files.FileField.get_prep_value` method and use my own model fields. Django even has a  14 years old ticket for this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10244 =)