# Count on filefield with None value is not zero

Tags: python, django

I have referred to the similar questions below:

[Django - FileField check if None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850415/django-filefield-check-if-none)

[How to save FileField with None in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312736/how-to-save-filefield-with-none-in-django)

Yet I am unable to solve my case.

My model FileField looks like:

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to=habCompletionDocPath, null=True)
```

I uploaded a file and deleted.

```
q = ProgressQty.objects.get(id=id)
q.document = None
q.save()
```

Now the value of the field is showing None:

```
In [80]: q.document
Out[80]: <FieldFile: None>
```

I need to count the number of files uploaded in the table.
However, I am unable to do so because of this:

```
ProgressQty.objects.exclude(document=None)
<ProgressQty: 269891toubul>
```

as I was expecting `<QuerySet []>`

How do I get correct result from this code:

```
objects.annotate(doc=Count('document'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I solved my case using:

```
doc=Count('document', filter=Q(document__gt=0))
```

Although this might not be the optimal solution.